# Instagram api - publish hashtag hook

Tags: php, hook, hashtag, instagram-api

Currently im working on task where i initially need to fetch media from instagram with specific hashtag and populate those info into database. After that, each new media published on instagram side (containing specific hashtag) needs to be fetched again and populated into database.

Of course i can accomplish this one using cron job (checking specific hashtag and number of media for that hashtag each 10 mins for example), but im wondering does instagram have "hooks" implemented for these kind of things. So for example, if something is published on instagram side, hook will be triggered and call will be sent to specific url provided within instagram dev app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out Instagram's Real-time API's: http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/
They allow you to subscribe and receive new contents via push updates. (uses pubsubhubbub)

Comment: quite embarrassing when i saw that on api page (its pretty much obvious). in my defense i checked the api page before asking a question.